# Is possible to determine beacon's location from Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android, beacon

Can beacon location be determined from an Android app?  If yes, could someone please give some info on how to do that?

In the past, I created an app that scanned for beacons and determined the android device location (i.e. the device that ran the app) but I wonder if the opposite is possible.  I've seen some on-line ads that claim just that.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have distance readings from three different sides of the beacon, and you have GPS readings of the 3 locations, then you can probably triage and calculate the beacons location from the Android's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard beacons just transmit a unique identifier.  **Nothing inherent to the beacon ties that identifier to a meaningful location like Latitude and Longitude**, although it is possible to use external databases or lookup tables to make this correlation.

Any claims you have seen probably use this technique.